# StackOverflowError exception when calling method

Tags: java

I am getting StackOverflowError overflow exception when calling a method that only contains print statement.

Below is the code

```
public class Dog {

    Dog dog = new Dog();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Dog().bark();
    }

    public void bark(){
        System.out.println("Bark");
    }

}
```

But when i remove the Class variable(dog), code is working fine.

Comment: @Ramanlfc: which is why I answered as a Community Wiki.

Comment: @Ramanlfc: found the dupe -- question closed. Note that given the original poster's newness, I'm guessing that he wouldn't know how to Google this *specific* problem.

Comment: You would have the same problem if you removed the `bark` and `main` contained only `new Dog();`. You need to practice the art of eliminating red herrings.

Comment: @all: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
public class Dog {

    Dog dog = new Dog();  //  ************** HERE ************

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Dog().bark();
    }

    public void bark(){
        System.out.println("Bark");
    }

}
```

Your Dog class is creating a new version of itself whenever it is created with the call to `new Dog()`, which creates version of itself, which creates version of itself, which creates version of itself, which creates version of itself, which creates version of itself, which creates version of itself, which creates version of itself, which creates version of itself, etc...

Solution: Don't create a `new Dog()` within the Dog class, except within the main method! Note that there are other times where it is OK to create a new instance of the object within itself, but always be watchful of possible recursion when doing this.